# InternalOAuthError: failed to fetch user profile using express and passport js while implementing twitter strategy

Tags: node.js, express, twitter, oauth, passport.js

Hello this is my first project using Express and Passport, also my first oauth experience. I did successfully implement Google and Facebook strategies but the Twitter one is resisting since two days ago. It seems the Twitter strategy is requiring session management in order to works so I manage to implement it already but now I am getting the following **InternalOAuthError: failed to fetch user profile** when it is loading the callback uri.
I will share a screenshot from sentry.io tracking issue:
[image]

There are some devtools screenshots as well:
[image]
[image]

This is my Twitter's strategy configuration:

```
const passport = require('passport')
const GoogleStrategy = require('passport-google-oauth').OAuth2Strategy
const FacebookStrategy = require('passport-facebook')
const TwitterStrategy = require('passport-twitter').Strategy
const User = require('../models/User')

passport.use('twitter', new TwitterStrategy({
  consumerKey: process.env.TWITTER_API_KEY,
  consumerSecret: process.env.TWITTER_API_SECRET,
  callbackURL: 'http://localhost:5000/auth/twitter/redirect'
}, async function (accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) {
  const response = await User.findOne({ twitterId: profile.id }).select('twitterId').lean()
  if (response) {
    done(null, profile)
  } else {
    const newUser = new User({
      user: profile.displayName,
      twitterId: profile.id,
      date: new Date()
    })
    await newUser.save().then(savedUser => {
      response.json(savedUser)
    }).catch(error => {
      console.error(error)
    })
    done(null, profile)
  }
}
))

passport.serializeUser((user, done) => {
  done(null, user.id)
})

passport.deserializeUser((id, done) => {
  User.findById(id)
    .then(user => {
      done(null, user)
    })
    .catch(e => {
      done(new Error('Failed to deserialize an user'))
    })
})
```

My Twitter's routes:

```
authRouter.get('/twitter', passport.authenticate('twitter'))

authRouter.get('/twitter/redirect',
  passport.authenticate('twitter', { failureRedirect: '/', session: true }),
  function (req, res) {
    console.log(req.user)
    res.send(req.user)
  })
```

Part of my index.js where the session is:

```
require('dotenv').config()
require('./mongo')
const express = require('express')
const expressSession = require('express-session')
const crypto = require('crypto')
const { v4: uuidv4 } = require('uuid')
const Sentry = require('@sentry/node')
const Tracing = require('@sentry/tracing')
const cors = require('cors')
const authRouter = require('./controllers/auth')
const usersRouter = require('./controllers/users')
const passport = require('passport')
require('./config/passport')

const notFound = require('./middlewares/notFound.js')
const handleErrors = require('./middlewares/handleErrors.js')

const app = express()
app.set('trust proxy', 1)
app.use(cors())
app.use(express.json())
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }))
app.use(expressSession(
  {
    secret: process.env.SESSION_SECRET,
    cookie: { secure: false },
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: false,
    genid: function (req) {
      return crypto.createHash('sha256').update(uuidv4()).update(crypto.randomBytes(256)).digest('hex')
    }
  }
))
app.use(passport.initialize())
app.use(passport.session())
```

And finally this is the model of my Users:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')

const { Schema, model } = mongoose

const userSchema = new Schema({
  user: String,
  email: String,
  facebookId: String,
  twitterId: String,
  date: Date
})

userSchema.set('toJSON', {
  transform: (document, returnedObject) => {
    returnedObject.id = returnedObject._id
    delete returnedObject._id
    delete returnedObject.__v
  }
})

const User = model('User', userSchema)

module.exports = User
```

As I said I already implemented Google and Facebook oauth login with very similar code but those never ask for session as Twitter is doing.

Thanks in advance, everyone. I really appreciate all the knowledge you always share with us.

Comment: I did a console.log() right at the line where the request is being sent and got this error: "You currently have Essential access which includes access to Twitter API v2 endpoints only. If you need access to this endpoint, you’ll need to apply for Elevated access via the Developer Portal."

Comment: Thanks, @Rachit Magon. I will try it out once I got the time to invest in this project once again, hope it is sooner than later. Cya.

Comment: Sure! I got it working after asking for 'Elevated Access' from Twitter.

Comment: Wow, thanks @RachitMagon I just ask for the Elevated access and every works great now. Don´t know why I didn't see that error msg before. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did a console.log() right at the line where the request is being sent and got this error: "You currently have Essential access which includes access to Twitter API v2 endpoints only.

If you need access to this endpoint, you’ll need to apply for Elevated access via the Developer Portal."

Answer (score 1):

You need to include the appropriate scopes in order to return user profile data.

Try this instead:

```js
router.get('/twitter', passport.authenticate('twitter', {
  scope: [
    'tweet.read',
    'users.read',
    'offline.access'
  ]
}));
```

You'll get back a profile object similar to:

```json
{
  "id": "0000000000000000000",
  "username": "xxxxxxxxxx",
  "displayName": "xxxxxxxxxx",
  "profileUrl": "",
  "photos": [
    {
      "value": "xxxxxxxxxx"
    }
  ],
  "provider": "twitter"
}
```

Twitter requires these three scopes in order to return user profile data:

- `offline.access` - Stay connected to your account until you revoke access.
- `users.read` - Any account you can view, including protected accounts.
- `tweet.read` - All the Tweets you can view, including Tweets from protected accounts.

You can read more about the available [Twitter scopes](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/authentication/oauth-2-0/authorization-code).

I'll note that `tweet.read` is an interesting scope. It's required by the [/2/users/me](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/users/lookup/api-reference/get-users-me) endpoint, which is used to return profile data on the authorized user. I would speculate that this is an oversight on Twitter's part.

I consider this scope an issue in a scenario where Twitter is being used only as a authorization flow. A user is presented this message on the authorization screen:

[image]

This messaging can be problematic in a B2C environment, where a customer may feel it's an over-reach.

Lastly, I'll mention that you will need an Elevated developer account if you wish to fetch additional profile data, notably a users email address.